# error in resize while uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading, image-resizing

I have to upload an image to uploads folder.code for uploading is given below

```
$profile_image    = 'profile_image';
$this->load->library('custom_upload_lib');
//get file extension
$fileExtension = "";
if($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]):
    // "profile_image" is the form input field name
    $path_info = pathinfo($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]); 
    $fileExtension    = $path_info['extension'];
endif;
$upload_path      = './uploads/profile_image/';
$allowed_types    = 'GIF|gif|PNG|png|jpg|JPEG|jpeg';
$max_size         = 2048;
$encrypt          = false;
$saved_file_name  = "profile_".rand(2,8)
                    .strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).'.'.$fileExtension;
//$saved_file_name=$_FILES["profile_image"]["name"];
$overwrite        = false;
$upload_control_name = $profile_image ;
$filePath            = "";
$uploadname          = "";
if($fileExtension != "") 
{
    $upload_data =  $this->custom_upload_lib->configure_upload($upload_path,
        $allowed_types,$max_size,$encrypt,$saved_file_name,
        $overwrite,$upload_control_name);
    if(is_array($upload_data)) 
    {
        $filePath         = $upload_data['full_path'];
        $uploadname       = 'profile_image/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
        $temp_upload_name = $upload_data['file_name'];

        $width  = 90;
        $height = 90;
        $this->load->library('resize_lib');
        $resize   = $this->resize_lib->_resizeImage( 
                        $filePath ,$temp_upload_name, $width, $height);

        if(!$resize) 
        {
            $message   = $resize;
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message );
            redirect(site_url('admin/preacher'));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $message   =  $upload_data;
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message );
        redirect(site_url('admin/preacher'));
    }
}
```

i have to resize the image to 90 X 90.But resize doesn't works..

Comment: Care to explain the problem? If you say "does not work" we can only reply "the code is wrong".

Comment: yes, please explain what the error is, how to reproduce the problem! you may also put the codes of resize_lib in pastebin and give link here.

Comment: The default library for resizing in CI is the [Image Manipulation Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html). If you're not using that library, then please let us see the code for your chosen library.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the image_lib. Use the code below to resize your images

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $upload_path.$saved_file_name;
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 90;
$config['height']   = 90;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->resize();
```